# Auto define default selected attribute values on WooCommerce variable products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, product-variations

In WooCommerce, If I have a product with only one option available, I need to pre select it.

I tried:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', 'fun_select_default_option', 10, 1);

function fun_select_default_option($args) {
    if (count($args['options']) === 1) {
        $onlyOption = reset($args['options']);
        if (!isset($onlyOption['disabled']) || !$onlyOption['disabled']) {
            $args['selected'] = $onlyOption;
        }
    }
    return $args;
}
```

This works if a dropdwown has only one option and that option is available. But not if there's 3 and one available.

So I tried filtering out available options but still does not work:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', 'fun_select_default_option', 10, 1);

function fun_select_default_option($args) {
    $selectableOptions = array_filter($args['options'], function($option) {
        return !isset($option['disabled']) || !$option['disabled'];
    });

    if (count($selectableOptions) === 1) {
        $onlyOption = reset($selectableOptions);
        $args['selected'] = $onlyOption;
    }

    return $args;
}
```

It should pre-select if only one option for attribute is available.

Example:

**Product 1**

Size: S ***M*** L (S L out of stock, M preselected)

Color: ***Blue*** (only available, pre selected)

**Product 2**

Size: **S** **M** **L** (all available, no preselection)

Color: Blue ***Red*** (Red available, preselected)

Comment: In admin edit product pages, for variables products, you can set a default product variation (or set the default attributes values)  like in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZNCo.png)… Or you can use `woocommerce_product_get_default_attributes` hook to set default attributes values.

Comment: I need it to be dynamic as I have 10k+ products. Also I can't forsee which attributes are available. For example if a product has 3 sizes but only M is in stock I need M to be pre selected.

Answer (score 0):

To auto define default variation attributes for variable products, you can use the following:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_default_attributes', 'auto_define_default_variation_attributes', 10, 2 );
function auto_define_default_variation_attributes( $default_attributes, $product ){
    $variation_attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();

    // Loop through available variations
    foreach( $product->get_available_variations('objects') as $variation ) {
        // Target purchasable in stock variation
        if ( $variation->is_purchasable() &&  $variation->is_in_stock() ) {
            // Loop through attributes for the current variation
            foreach( $variation->get_attributes() as $attribute => $value ) {
                if ( ! empty($value) ) {
                    $default_attributes[$attribute] = $value;
                } else {
                    // If there is no defined value, set it
                    foreach( $variation_attributes as $variation_attribute => $values ) {
                        if ( $attribute === sanitize_title($variation_attribute) ) {
                            $default_attributes[$attribute] = current($values);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }
    return $default_attributes; // Always return the values in a filter hook
}
```

Code goes on functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

**Note:** The code handle WooCommerce product attributes and custom attributes for variations.

Comment: This kind of works but it has a problem, if a variable product has one color available but many sizes available, it will select the color and one of the sizes (can't say based on what). It should only select the one color and keep the size dropdown on "choose an option". Also if there's more than one color it will pre select one. I need pre-selection only if 1 term per attribute is selectable.

Comment: @Filippo It works and has no problems, the problem is your question that is quite unclear. With this code, you have everything needed to customize it for your needs.

Comment: The request is to preselect if only one term is available, your code always preselect regardless of availability. I have updated the post with examples.

Comment: Your example is not really logic, so too complicated to be handled automatically for all products. Try to tweak yourself the code to get what you want (if you can).